# Track messenger messages in ISA server?

Tags: security, isa-server, instant-messaging

As all of my internet traffic goes through an ISA server, is it possible to extract the content of IM messages from the logs?

It's ISA 2004 running on 2K3 Server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc722766.aspx

Make sure you have plenty of free disk space though!

JR